# MOSFETs for 30A motor control comparison

Tags: motor-controller

We are currently develop a 30A continous BLDC motor controller, running on +48VDC. The first prototyp is running fine so far, but at 30A the controller goes hot pretty fast and needs a thermal current reduction (NTC onboard, triggering at 120°C (100°C over ambient) and reducing maximum current). The goal is to keep the maximum temperature without cooling at around 40-45°C above ambient.

Currently we are using these MOSFETs: BSC040N08NS5ATMA1 (https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BSC040N08NS5-DataSheet-v02_02-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4624ad04ef9014ae3065a7e2a05)

Now we are looking to switch to another MOSFET of the same package, but with less total losses, so far we found this type here: NVMFS6H800NL (https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nvmfs6h800nl-d.pdf)

So, the question is, what we can expect from a change of the MOSFETs in therms of losses. The RDSon goes down from maximum 7mOhm at 140°C to around 4.1mOhm at the same temperatur, so this should already make a huge part of the loss reduction. But now there are the switching losses and since Coss increases, the question is, what additional losses there will occur and how we can calculate them?

**Specifications:**

- **30A** phase current
- 6 MOSFET inverter stage
- **+48VDC** input voltage (chopping at +55VDC, that is the reason for 80VDC break through voltage of the FETs)
- **24kHz** PWM für switching
- Motor can be blocked, so the whole current can go through one phase the whole time in worst case

**Edit:**
I search for further sources for a rough estimation and found this: (https://www.maxlinear.com/appnote/anp-20.pdf)

[image]

So the high side MOSFET will have the most switching losses through the dependency of Vin and in my case, this part makes around 7.7W of power losses (300ns tR and 150ns tF). The tR and tF I can directly choose, since we are using a TI smart gate driver (DRV8350), where the slew rate can directly be controlled, knowing the gate charge.

So the switching loss will be the same for both MOSFETs, since I will just increase the gate driver current for the double gate charge to achieve the same rise and fall time. So in the end, I save only around the 1.7W from the conduction losses. Anyway, a cooler will be necessary.

**Edit 2:**
I made some measurements on the same setup for different switching speeds:

[image]

The setup was for all the same and the motor was always blocked at the exact same position and the steady state was achieved, when for 5min the temperature did not change.

So, the switching losses are proportional to the phase current and the conduction losses are quadratic in the phase current. To me, this looks like the conduction losses dominate or am I wrong?

Comment: Instead of numerically doing a bunch of different scenarios, use a simulation tool to get your many-different-scenario answers.

Comment: I'd say put it in PLEC or similar simulation tool and get the numbers out of that. Then your computer does the maths and gives you all the outcomes wiht all the different combination of inputs you could want.

Comment: It halves the Rdson, but doubles the gate charge... What does your thermal solution look like?

Comment: The obvious improvement to me is PWM soft start with reduced acceleration and "locked rotor" current sensing.

Comment: Allowing > 100mJ = I^2R*t dissipation is a problem so design for lower startup

Comment: Hmm ok, I will try out a simulator. But a rough estimation of the power losses would be great. For 24kHz, 48VDC and a total gate charge of 112nC, there is only a loss of 0.13W, in comparison to the half RDSon, that makes out around 1.8W. Do I need to take other charges into account for the switching losses?

Comment: You are about to swap the lower gate charge Qg MOSFET with higher Qg. I doubt that the losses are mostly conductive nature, but rather switching losses.  So you can expect even higher temperatures with new selection. You should work around gate driver and thermal construction of your PCB. Show some details.

Comment: Have you investigated what proportion of your losses are RdsON versus switching? (try changing the frequency). Have you checked the FETs do not avalanche and waste power due to voltage spikes? What is the fastest switching you can use while still meeting EMI? How is the dead time? Have you checked for cross conduction? Body diode recovery? Are your paralleled FETs switching at the same time?

Comment: I changed already the switching frequency from 32kHz to 24kHz, the temperature changed around 20°C. I will further evaluate that. There is nearly no overshoot (around 5V for 20ns) so I think I can potentially switch faster and so save more energy, but the threshold of the controller for ringing is 10V, pretty low and TI recommends a setting of 300ns/150ns for turn on. The deadtime is 100ns (constant on that controller). There is no cross conduction, when the controller has nearly no current, the FETs stay at around 30°C. Body diode recovery is not that much power and no parallel FETs are used.

Comment: How much energy is stored in your output capacitors i.e. what is CV^/2 and D.F. at fsw

Comment: Coss is 500pF, so there is around a power loss of C V^2 f = 0.028W, that should be negligible

Comment: Higher frequency means higher switching losses. Switching faster does not save you energy. Switching more slowly will save you energy if your switching losses are a substantial portion of your total losses. It is good to keep the switching frequency higher than the audible frequency for humans. So I would not go too much less than 24 kHz. When the switching frequency is in the audible range, the BLDC stator will whine and people can hear it.

Comment: The switching losses in the gate are only one part of the switching losses. The FET does not transition instantly from infinity ohms to Rds(on). During the transition, when the FET is turning on, the FET dissipates power according to Id * Vds.